# Play Resource MP3s

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I want to create an iPod-like application that will play only MP3 files I have inside the resource folder of the project.

Which way should I do it?

Comment: This might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625155/playing-mp3-from-nsbundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### .h file

```
#include <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface audioplayer : NSObject 
<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    NSTimer * timer;
    AVAudioPlayer * audio;
}
@end
```

### .m file

```
// start plying music
@implementation audioplayer
- (void)main 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundfile" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    audio.delegate = self;
    [audio play];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(playSequence) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    
}
// display the time playing
- (void) playSequence{
    if(audio.playing){
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", audio.currentTime]);
    } else {
        [timer invalidate];
    }    
}
@end
```

Comment: Works great - thank you.
How can I get the track data - like Artist and Title?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html